# Converting HTML to RDF

Tags: html, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I'm looking for a general purpose API/web service/tool/etc... that allows convert a given HTML page to an RDF graph as specific as possible (most probably using a back bone ontology and/or mapper).

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of the HTML document? Or does it have to be any random document?

Comment: It can be any HTML doc. I need to extract the structure of the HTML doc into an RDF graph. If the conversion uses a backbone mapper/ontology then its even better.

Comment: It looks like XSPARQL can achieve this with a custom query written according an ontology...

Comment: By "structure of HTML doc" you mean structure of `div's`, `p's` and so on? Take for example this SO page: what would be your desired RDF output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used XQuery to extract the data out of the given set of web pages. I had to write custom queries for the web pages. I think this is the most straight forward approach to take for a specific set of HTML files. However, it is obviously not good for the general case. For a different set of web pages other custom queries are need to be written.

Answer (score 2):

Have you proved [GRDDL](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/GRDDL)?

> GRDDL is a technique for obtaining RDF
>   data from XML documents and in
>   particular XHTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

I used JSoup to scrape data from HTML. It uses jQuery style of querying HTML DOM, wich I was already famirial with, so it was realy simple tool to use for me. I also fund it quite robust but I needed it just to scrape 3 datasources so I dont have rich experience with this tool yet. [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)