# Converting HTML file into RDF file

Tags: html, rdf

i was wondering if there is any way/tool to convert a HTML file into its equivalent RDF file.

Thnx in advance. ur help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As long as your html is well formed and valid, it should be possible to do it using XSLT

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335321/converting-html-to-rdf

Comment: n wat do we mean by the word "well-formed HTML page"???

Answer (score 3):

There is not a standard equivalent RDF representation from arbitrary HTML.  If you have highly regular pages, you could do something with XSLT or just simple XML parsing to scrape RDF from them.  iirc, this is how the DBPedia project got its data originally, by scraping wikipedia pages which tend to be very regular in format, particularly those side boxes on each page.

But to this in the general case is not really possible.  One thing that might interest you is [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/) which is the w3c standard on how to *embed* RDF in HTML.

Comment: by the word "highly regular pages" ,do u mean embedded RDF???

Comment: if ur answer is yes, then as per my knowledge,most of the existing webpages(almost 100%) does not have embedded RDF into their html pages....

then is there any way that can help me extract/create a RDF out of a  simple HTML page??

Comment: No, by highly regular pages i mean pages that are valid XHTML which are likely generated from a template.  I gave you the example of wikipedia pages; they conform to a very regular template from which you could make some generalizations and extract some RDF.  But generally, this is not possible.  And yes, most pages do not already embed RDF via RDFa.  You won't magically get RDF out of HTML pages.  HTML is for presenting knowledge in human understandable format, RDF is about presenting knowledge in machine understandable format.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, not really. Reading [this](http://internet-apps.blogspot.com/2007/10/converting-html-to-rdf.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876179/converting-websites-in-html-xml-into-rdf) may help you understand why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal way of doing this. There is a namespace for the XHTML vocabulary:

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#

And a namespace for XHTML

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

Which could entail some uris for HTML elements, either properties or classes. You could also use bits and pieces from Dublin Core.